# Python - Mapping a Key to a Value that is a Map

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to map a string to a map in Python. For example, if I want a map that looks like:

mymap = { 'ABC': {'123' : 56}, 'DEF': {'456' : 92}  }

Is this possible? How would I add a value to the map, or check the map to see what the value is of the 'inner map' if I am doing an iteration when mymap is empty (at the start of a loop, for example). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> mymap = defaultdict(dict)
>>> mymap['ABC'] = {'123' : 56}
>>> mymap
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'ABC': {'123': 56}})
```

can you try this snippet, hope this solves your purpose

Comment: So if I have {'ABC': {'123': 56}}), how can I check to see that '56' is associated with 'ABC'? (The '123' is also important, but not directly in this step). Each inner dict will only have one pair (would it make more sense to have a tuple instead of a dict)?

Comment: Only recently learnt about `defaultdict`, very useful indeed.

Comment: @biocompamateur yes a tuple would be better (or a list if you want to change one of the values) if you only have a pair of values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. If you aren't sure is `mymap` has elements and don't want to do a `try except` you can use the `dict.get(key, default)` method:

```
value = mymap.get('ABC', {}).get('123', None)
if values is not None:
    # Found key 123 inside mymap['ABC']
else:
    # mymap['123'] or mymap['123']['ABC'] doesn't exist
```